# lubuntu pcmanfm recently opened files and folder (history)

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

Is their a way to see and open recently viewed files and folders  (history) in PCManFM in Lubuntu? The recent files appears only sometimes (eg. during file open/file save) as in the picture [open/save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fww6p.png)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this is you go to view and make sure pathbar is set for buttons. Then type recent:// into this and you will see your recently used files. If you want to make this quicker you can even make a bookmark for it in pcmanfm by pressing control d .

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time. Thanks !!